# electron tray app - ui window covered by taskbar popup menu

Tags: javascript, c++, electron, taskbar

I have an electron tray app that, when its icon is clicked, opens a ui window. The only thing is that taskbar menu covers it awkwardly, even if I focus the ui BrowserWindow. User has to move mouse to hover over part of the ui window and wait for a few seconds before it closes. Does anyone know either a way to put it in front, or to close the taskbar menu using either c++ or electron?

[image: y app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with c++. I call this via node-addon to close the tray notification overflow when the icon is clicked:

```
HWND overflow = FindWindow(L"NotifyIconOverflowWindow", NULL);
if (overflow != NULL && IsWindowVisible(overflow)) {
    PostMessage(overflow, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
}
```